# Cisco 2821 call history SetupTime

Tags: cisco

Сisco logs (`show call history voice`) have parameter `SetupTime`.
in what format this parameter? Example:

```
SetupTime=780535960 ms
```

Milliseconds since what time?

Answer (score 1):

It is the number of milliseconds since the router booted. From the documentation:

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3/vvf_r/vrg_sh1_ps1839_TSD_Products_Command_Reference_Chapter.html#wp1161535

> **SetupTime**
>
> Value of the system UpTime, in milliseconds, when the call associated with this entry was started.